# How to append array on dictionary based on element exists

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

On print  po menuList?[1]["subMenu"]

I got below message

```
▿ Optional<Any>
  ▿ some : 1 element
    ▿ 0 : 1 element
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : subItem
        ▿ value : 4 elements
          ▿ 0 : 7 elements
            ▿ 0 : 2 elements
              - key : permission
              - value : access
            ▿ 1 : 2 elements
              - key : title
              - value : Create
            ▿ 2 : 2 elements
              - key : bar
              - value : sidebar
            ▿ 3 : 2 elements
              - key : isNotify
              - value : 0
            ▿ 4 : 2 elements
              - key : link
              - value : linker
            ▿ 5 : 2 elements
              - key : path
              - value : /dashboard
            ▿ 6 : 2 elements
              - key : icon
              - value : add
```

Trying to extract `menuList?[i]["subMenu"]["subItem"]` based on condition if value exist in side subItem then append to array else not.

few cases ["subItem"] may have 0 elements

```
    if let permissionList =  MenuList?[i]["subMenu"] {
        let subMenu =  (permissionList as AnyObject)
        if subMenu.count > 0 {
            for j in 0..<subMenu.count{
             let subItem =  subMenu["subItem"]
            }
        }
```

Its return nil for me

On try subMenu[0]
error: ambiguous use of 'subscript(_:)'
subMenu[0]

Comment: What have you tried? How was the result different than what you expected?

Comment: @jnpdx I updated question what i have tried.

Comment: In your sample data you printed, `subItem` only appears after two levels of arrays. Right now, it looks like you're just one level deep.

Comment: @kiran What's the type of `menuList`? It would help to figure this out.

Comment: @George_E var menuList: [[String: Any]]? its array of dictionary

Comment: @kiran Ok, thanks. Can you be a bit clearer on what exactly you need? From what I have gathered: iterating through each element of the `menuList` array, if there is an element at `menuList?[I]["subMenu"]["subItem"]`, add it to an array. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes You are correct

Comment: do I need to change  (permissionList as AnyObject) to  as! Array<Any>   &                         let subItem =  subMenu[j] as! Dictionary<String, Any>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variant of George's function, expressing using a map operation rather than a hand-rolled loop:

```
func menuResult() -> [String] {
    // FIXME: Why is this even optional in the first place?
    guard let menuList = menuList else { return [] }

    return menuList.compactMap { menu -> [String] in
        guard let subMenu = menu["subMenu"] as? [String: String] else { return nil }
        return subMenu["subItem"]
    }
}
```

Comment: or simply `(menu["subMenu"] as? [String: String])?["subItem"]`. Single line is also preferred as it benefits type inference. Not sure but `menuList?.compactMap { ($0["subMenu"] as? [String: String])?["subItem"] } ?? []` should work

Comment: @LeoDabus Yep, though I avoided going that far because debugging that was really a pain. Maybe now that Xcode lets you place breakpoints within expressions, expressions like this might be more reasonable to work with

Answer (score 0):

For example `menuData` like this:

```
let menuList: [[String: Any]]? = [
    ["abc": [
        "123": "test1",
        "456": "test2"
    ]],
    ["def": [
        "789": "test3",
        "101112": "test4"
    ]],
    ["subMenu": [
        "subItem": "Other correct path" // <- subMenu[2]["subMenu"]["subItem"]
    ]],
    ["subMenu": [
        "otherItem": "WRONG",
        "subItem": "CORRECT" // <- subMenu[3]["subMenu"]["subItem"]
    ]]
]
```

Code to get all items in the `menuData` array at `menuData[i]["subMenu"]["subItem"]`:

```
func menuResult() -> [String] {
    // menuList can't start nil
    guard let menuList = menuList else { return [] }
    var result = [String]()

    // Iterate every element of menuList
    for i in menuList.indices {
        // Get 'subMenu' dictionary if it exists
        if let subMenu = menuList[i]["subMenu"] as? [String: String] {
            // Get 'subItem' dictionary if it exists
            if let subItem = subMenu["subItem"] {
                // Store value at this path
                result.append(subItem)
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

```
print(menuResult())
// Prints: ["Other correct path", "CORRECT"]
```

Comment: Your `for` loop can be replaced with a simple `compactMap`.

Comment: Might I also suggest removing comment like `// Return result` when the code literally says `return result`. There should be a really high bar for what gets commented.

Comment: I have some tips/tricks that might benefit this code, if you're interested. Would be easier to discuss them in SE chat, though

Comment: @Alexander Tbh, I think I just got a little bit carried away with the comments here  Looking back it definitely has got quite a few inefficiencies (such as the index, not really neededP

Comment: I don't use twitter, but I'd be happy to chat here. A chatroom link should be offered if we spam comments back and forth a few more times

Comment: Also, this really shouldn't have any performance boost compared to compactMap. I'd be surprised if they didn't get compiled to exactly the exact same instructions

Comment: I think in some situations a `for` can be optimised better by the compiler, but probably in most cases not much difference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235570/discussion-between-alexander-and-george-e).